# Unable to comunicate from WCF to Web Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, service, windows-services

I have recently developed a asp mvc 4 application in vs 2017 express and published that to local folder. Also developed a windows service to be hosted on 4 local machine. Web application is hosted on local IIS and working fine. Now, the proble is that

> How do I communicate from Web app to windows service with push notifications? To be send from browser to service once web application gets updated ?
>
> Need to send push notification to each service with specific IP hosted in different local machines when triggered ?

What needs to be done to interact between the applications ?
Please help me solve this.

Comment: You want to send push notification from Service to Browser or in reverse? Title and question content looks unrelated??? [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) could be a fit. Just evaluate for your purpose.

Comment: Need to send notification to client service from web application hosted in local IIS, WCF services are installed in client machine . All services to be hosted locally without internet connection. All clients are in a connected environment with unique ip each.